# Select variable between two constant strings in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi there and thank you for reviewing my question!

In a vendor supplied MS SQL database we can add user defined fields via a GUI which populates the data as an xml string the the table.  I would like to be able to run a query that will strip the XML and leave me with the data in between.

Here's an example of the data in the UDF column

```
<udf><udf_date_induction>2013-11-19</udf_date_induction>
```

In my example I want to dynamically remove everything left and right of the date (which is a variable) `2013-11-19`, these are constants and it is acceptible to reference them.

```
<udf><udf_date_induction>
```

and

```
</udf_date_induction>
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using, and would every entry in the `UDF` column _always_ have the same exact XML tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will give you idea to work :

```
declare @val varchar(100)
set @val='<udf><udf_date_induction>2013-11-19</udf_date_induction>'
start:
if (charindex('<',@val)=1)
begin
set @val=substring(@val,charindex('<',@val)+charindex('>',@val),len(@val))
goto start
end
print substring(@val,0,charindex('<',@val))
```

Comment: Thanks for the responce but I can't set the @val of 2013-11-19, it's the varible

Comment: just pull the value from table in which the information is stored and run the above query through cursor and update table with new value. I was just giving idea of how it can be done :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case a function is suitable to fetch the date.

Schema for your case (Assume it as your actual table)

```
    CREATE TABLE #TAB (DATEINXML VARCHAR(MAX))
    INSERT INTO #TAB

    SELECT  '<udf><udf_date_induction>2013-11-19</udf_date_induction>'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '<udf><udf_date_induction>2014-12-20</udf_date_induction>'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '<udf><udf_date_induction>2015-01-21</udf_date_induction>'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  '<udf><udf_date_induction>2016-02-22</udf_date_induction>'
```

So the Data present in your table

```
    +----------------------------------------------------------+
    |                        DATEINXML                         |
    +----------------------------------------------------------+
    | <udf><udf_date_induction>2013-11-19</udf_date_induction> |
    | <udf><udf_date_induction>2014-12-20</udf_date_induction> |
    | <udf><udf_date_induction>2015-01-21</udf_date_induction> |
    | <udf><udf_date_induction>2016-02-22</udf_date_induction> |
    +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now create one User Defined function which will accept your column and giving the date from xml part. (I have used recursive CTE with Stuff function used)

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_GETDATEFROMXML](@VAR VARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS VARCHAR(50)
     AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @DATA VARCHAR(50)
        ;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT 1 AS START,CHARINDEX('<',@VAR,1 ) FIRST_IND,CHARINDEX('>',@VAR,1 ) SECOND_IND ,   STUFF(@VAR,CHARINDEX('<',@VAR,1 ),CHARINDEX('>',@VAR,1 ),'') AS DATA
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(SECOND_IND+1 AS INT),CHARINDEX('<',DATA,1 ) FIRST_IND,CHARINDEX('>',DATA,1 ) SECOND_IND , STUFF(DATA,CHARINDEX('<',DATA,1 ),CHARINDEX('>',DATA,1 ),'') DATA FROM CTE 
WHERE CHARINDEX('<',DATA,1 ) <>0
    )
    SELECT @DATA= DATA FROM CTE WHERE START= (SELECT MAX(START) FROM CTE )

          RETURN @DATA      
    END
```

Now call this UDF on your table column like below

```
    SELECT DATEINXML, DBO.[FN_GETDATEFROMXML](DATEINXML) AS DATE_FROM_XML FROM #TAB
```

Result will be

```
    +----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
    |                        DATEINXML                         | DATE_FROM_XML |
    +----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
    | <udf><udf_date_induction>2013-11-19</udf_date_induction> | 2013-11-19    |
    | <udf><udf_date_induction>2014-12-20</udf_date_induction> | 2014-12-20    |
    | <udf><udf_date_induction>2015-01-21</udf_date_induction> | 2015-01-21    |
    | <udf><udf_date_induction>2016-02-22</udf_date_induction> | 2016-02-22    |
    +----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```